# GCD and delegation on which thread?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, delegation

I am trying to figure out if this code is updating the UI on the main thread. This code is in a class I made specifically for downloading the JSON feed. After getting the data, I parse it to return an array I will use to update the UI, and then let the delegate know the data is ready. My delegate, a view controller, will use this array to update the UI. Do I need to do the `-parser:didFinishParsingWithResults:` in a `dispatch_get_main_queue` block? Or is that not necessary since I am updating UI in the view controller class and not this class? Thank you!

```
__block NSArray *results;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    results = [self parseData:responseData];
    [self.delegate parser:self didFinishParsingWithResults:results];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

That ain't the main thread.   That is the default priority global queue which might be any thread.

If `parser:didFinishParsingWithResults:` diddles UI elements without dispatching to the main queue / thread, then you have a problem.

Comment: Got it! I just wasn't sure if telling the delegate means it automatically goes back onto the main thread. Don't know why I made such an assumption. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to update your UI, that code's not thread safe, so you'll always want to update your UI on the main thread. I learned this the hard way :-)